# Perform a different task each time a bash script is executed

Tags: linux, bash

Lets say I have 2 tasks.
Is it possible to write a bash script (one script) that should execute 1st task when we run first time and 2nd task when we run the script second time and again 1st task when we run 3rd time and 2nd script when we run 4th time?

Comment: You can have an external file to store the number of times it ran.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its easy to do this by remembering/persisting what was run the last time.

```
$ echo "1" > current_counter
$ cat current_counter 
1
$ vim main.bash
$ cat main.bash 
#/bin/bash
current_counter=$(<"current_counter")
if [[ "$((${current_counter}%2))" -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo "Running task 1"
else
    echo "Running task 2"
fi
echo "$((${current_counter}+1))" > "current_counter"
$ bash main.bash 
Running task 1
$ cat current_counter 
2
$ bash main.bash 
Running task 2
$ cat current_counter 
3
$ bash main.bash 
Running task 1
$ cat current_counter 
4
$ bash main.bash 
Running task 2
$ cat current_counter 
5
$
```

You could also use a Boolean 0 or 1 in the current_counter file or just by checking the existence of a file but it will work only for this case. Above script scales easily if you have more tasks (not just 2) like 3 or even 100; then you just have to change the modulus number and add more conditions to handle each residue.

Comment: You can drop the `|| [[ -n "$line" ]]` hack; it is only needed to accommodate invalid POSIX text files (i.e., Windows text files) that don't correctly end with a newline character.

Comment: I've used cat instead of while, I found it simpler to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I found too hard to read ritesht93 script, so I made my own.

**Bash Version**

**Running the script provides this output:**

```
{ ~ }  » ./test.sh                                                                                                                                       ~
First Run
{ ~ }  » ./test.sh                                                                                                                                       ~
Second Run
{ ~ }  » ./test.sh                                                                                                                                       ~
Third Run
{ ~ }  »
```

**First we create a file with the number 1 on it:**

```
{ ~ }  » echo 1 > counter
```

**Script content (test.sh):**

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

foo=`cat counter`

if [ $foo -eq '1' ]
        then
                echo "First Run"
                echo '2' > counter
fi

if [ $foo -eq 2 ]
        then
                echo "Second Run"
                echo '3' > counter
fi

if [ $foo -eq 3 ]
        then
                echo "Third Run"
                # after 3 times we reset
                echo '1' > counter
fi
```

**Python 3.0 Version (if needed)**

I had time to do it in python as well:

**First we create a file with the number 1 on it:**

```
{ ~ }  » echo 1 > counter
```

Script content:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python

with open('counter','r+') as file :
    for l in file :
            #print(type(l))
            line = l.strip()

            if line == '1' :
                    print ('this is line 1')
                    file.seek(0)
                    file.truncate()
                    file.write('2')
            elif line == '2' :
                    print ('this is line 2')
                    file.seek(0)
                    file.truncate()
                    file.write('3')
            elif line == '3' :
                    print ('this is line 3')
                    file.seek(0)
                    file.truncate()
                    file.write('1')
            else :
                    print ("I'm lost, reset the counter")
```

Answer (score 0):

It´s even easier than the two previous answers. Just create an empty control file. `Touch control` and delete with `rm control`for example.

When you run it you check if it exists, if it does you destroy it and run the second task, if not run the first and create it.

You dont need to check anything inside the file just its existence.

Edit

```
#!/bin/bash
$FILE=filename
if [-f $FILE] 
then
#Task1
rm $FILE
else
#Task2
touch $FILE
fi
```

You can add more tasks by using different names as the next script:

```
#!/bin/bash
$FILE1=filename1
$FILE2=filename2

if [-f $FILE1] 
then
#Task1
mv $FILE1  $FILE2
elif [-f $FILE2]
then
#Task2
rm $FILE2
else 
#Task3
touch %FILE1
fi
```

Anyways I think the use of this with more than 2 tasks its not a good idea.

Comment: I like the way you think. You should provide an script for that. Anyway that would limit the execution for two tasks. Reading the file adds flexibility for more than 2 executions.

Other thing is I always avoid the use of rm in scripting. But under certain circunstances would be a good approach.

Comment: I added the script in case you wanted to see it.